# Binding RViz' view camera position and orientation to tf frame

Tags: rviz, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on head-tracking application and utilizing RViz for visualization. I have 3 coordinate frames connected as **/world** -> **/base** -> **/head**.

- **/world** - global frame
- **/base** - head-tracker frame (fixed to **/world**)
- **/head** - user's head frame in **/base**

The thing I am trying to achive is make user's head to be a 'camera' in 3D environment. Thus, I need to make **/head** frame to control RViz' viewport camera position and orientation. So far I managed only to bind **/head** frame position to the RViz camera by setting it to Target Frame. But frame orientation is ignored in this case.

Is there a way to control RViz camera orientation as well?

Thanks in advance,

Boris

**UPDATE**: Setting fixed frame to /world or /base does not help.

**UPDATE 2**:

```
$ rosrun tf tf_echo /world /base
At time 1342851117.156
- Translation: [0.000, 0.000, 0.500]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.500, 0.500, 0.500, 0.500]
            in RPY [1.570, -0.000, 1.570]
// -- duplicating messages -- //
```

```
$ rosrun tf tf_echo /base /head
At time 1342851130.635
- Translation: [-0.183, 0.029, -0.722]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.010, 0.269, -0.049, 0.962]
            in RPY [-0.008, 0.544, -0.104]
At time 1342851131.636
- Translation: [-0.176, 0.028, -0.732]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.037, 0.984, -0.176, 0.018]
            in RPY [-2.789, 0.049, 3.075]
At time 1342851132.631
- Translation: [-0.181, 0.020, -0.745]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.041, 0.978, -0.201, 0.025]
            in RPY [-2.739, 0.066, 3.072]
// -- and so on -- //
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39118/binding-rviz%27-view-camera-position-and-orientation-to-tf-frame/) by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3060 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-20**:
What type of view do you have rviz set to? Orbit? FPS? etc?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-07-20**:
I tried both Orbit and FPS, does make a big difference. I can see how /head frame is rotating with respect to RViz camera plane. However I need opposite effect - /head frame has to be completely fixed to RViz camera frame.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-21**:
I am confused about your intention. Do you want the head and camera to stay fixed in rviz and the world to rotate as the head does?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2012-07-23**:
@joq: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like that "not recommended" option from Wiki suits my needs best, i.e. setting up both **Target Frame** and **Fixed Frame** to **/head** (moving frame).

P.S. I was ignoring this option thinking that view jittering is caused by such setup, but eventually it is because of head tracking errors.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jiaxin](https://answers.ros.org/users/58585/jiaxin/) on 2020-08-25**:
saved my life, are there any "official" support from rviz for this kind of need?